# How can I run the selenium test case?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

I wrote a selenium sample test case in my application. Then I right click the file and select "Test File". It results

```
Testsuite: com.MyApp.SampleSeleniumTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Time elapsed: 0.265 sec

Testcase: warning(junit.framework.TestSuite$1): FAILED
No tests found in com.MyApp.SampleSeleniumTest
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No tests found in com.MyApp.SampleSeleniumTest
Test com.MyApp.SampleSeleniumTest FAILED
```

My code is

```
package com.MyApp;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SampleSeleniumTest extends SeleneseTestCase {

   @Override
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
      setUp("http://www.google.com", "*firefox");
   }

   @Test
   public void whatever() throws Exception {
       selenium.open("/");
       assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Explore"));
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using JUnit 4.x ? Otherwise you can't use annotations.

Comment: Yes I'm using JUnit 4.8.2. Its working now. Anyway thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternate way to do the same

```
package com.MyApp;

import com.thoughtworks.selenium.*;
import org.junit.*;

public class SampleSeleniumTest extends SeleneseTestCase {

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://urlofyourApp");
        selenium.start();
    }

    @Test
    public void testTestRC() throws Exception {
        selenium.open("/");
    assertTrue(selenium.isTextPresent("Explore"));

    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        selenium.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Prashant, Thanks for your reply. But Still i'm getting the same error

Comment: @Gnik: You are using netbeans, right? Try naming the test method so that it start with test like 'testWhatever()'